# Errors trying to install newman

Tags: node.js, installation, npm, postman, newman

I have node and npm installed on my windows 7 system and am attempting to install newman to use with [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/newman_intro)

The command for this I am using is `npm install -g newman`

I get an error involving contextify and node-gyp.js on attempting this:

```
16878 verbose stack Error: contextify@0.1.14 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
16878 verbose stack Exit status 1
16878 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:214:16)
16878 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
16878 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
16878 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
16878 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
16878 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
16878 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:817:16)
16878 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
16879 verbose pkgid contextify@0.1.14
16880 verbose cwd C:\Users\Anthony\AppData\Roaming\npm
16881 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
16882 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "newman"
16883 error node v4.1.0
16884 error npm  v2.14.3
16885 error code ELIFECYCLE
16886 error contextify@0.1.14 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
16886 error Exit status 1
16887 error Failed at the contextify@0.1.14 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
16887 error This is most likely a problem with the contextify package,
16887 error not with npm itself.
16887 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
16887 error     node-gyp rebuild
16887 error You can get their info via:
16887 error     npm owner ls contextify
16887 error There is likely additional logging output above.
16888 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
16889 verbose unbuild node_modules\newman\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify
```

from the logs. I used the 64 bit msi installer for node which included npm along with it any insight on to what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to V8 API changes [introduced](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v4.0.0/CHANGELOG.md#notable-changes) in Node.js v4, `contextify` does not yet support Node.js v4. Adding such support is in progress over at [brianmcd/contextify#180](https://github.com/brianmcd/contextify/issues/180). Either downgrade to Node.js v0.12 or use the branch of `contextify` wherein development of Node.js v4 support is taking place.

Comment: installing the older version of node worked, thanks!

Comment: was getting a similar `node-gyp` issue, and this was the fix for me as of 02 Oct 2015